# Java convert seconds to days, hours, minutes, seconds with unique outputs

Tags: java, converters

So I need to convert seconds to days, hours minutes seconds.

But I need to have unique outputs for the times and if they return a zero not include them in the response.

So if 3600 seconds in input it needs to return 1 hour and nothing else.  How do I skip a line if a response is returned 0.

Here is the code that I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ps9 {
public static void main(String [] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of seconds");
    int input = in.nextInt();

    int numberOfDays;
    int numberOfHours;
    int numberOfMinutes;
    int numberOfSeconds;

    numberOfDays = input / 86400;
    numberOfHours = (input % 86400 ) / 3600 ;
    numberOfMinutes = ((input % 86400 ) % 3600 ) / 60;
    numberOfSeconds = ((input % 86400 ) % 3600 ) % 60;

    if (numberOfDays > 0) {
        System.out.println(numberOfDays + " day(s)");
        if (numberOfHours != 0)
        System.out.println(numberOfHours + " hour(s)");
        nextLine;
        System.out.println(numberOfMinutes + " minute(s)");
        System.out.println(numberOfSeconds + " second(s)");
    }
     else if (numberOfHours >= 0 )
    {
        System.out.println(numberOfHours +" hour(s)");
        System.out.println(numberOfMinutes + " minute(s)");
        System.out.println(numberOfSeconds + " second(s)");
    }
    else if (numberOfMinutes >= 0 )
    {
        System.out.println(numberOfMinutes + " minute(s)");
        System.out.println(numberOfSeconds + " second(s)");
    }
    else if (numberOfSeconds >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println(numberOfSeconds + " second(s)");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I’m think StringBuilder, simple walk from the highest value to lowest, including all none zero values

Comment: I dont know how to do that yet

Comment: You could put the line that you (sometimes) want to suppress inside the scope of an `if` statement.  The code you've exhibited shows that you already know how to do this.

Comment: Do you care about years, months?

Comment: But how do I skip the true result isnt that how that works.  If i put in 3600 seconds and it equates to 1 hour, I want to skip the println results of minutes and seconds because they would both result 0.  Would I use a != 0 null command?  I have never done the skipping of a line before so I dont know how.

Comment: Instead of `if-else` use `if`, as you want include each value which isn’t zero

Comment: Oh man you are awesome!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  Works perfect

Comment: Yeah, `if minutes != 0` will print nothin

Answer (score 6):

Since you only want to skip an output when it’s 0, use a series of `if` statements instead of `if-else`, as you want to execute those statements independently of each other.

This will reduce possible code duplications

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds(3660);
long days = d.toDays();
d = d.minusDays(days);
long hours = d.toHours();
d = d.minusHours(hours);
long mins = d.toMinutes();
d = d.minusMinutes(mins);
long seconds = d.getSeconds();

if (days > 0) {
    System.out.println(days + " day(s)");
}
if (hours > 0) {
    System.out.println(hours + " hour(s)");
}
if (mins > 0) {
    System.out.println(mins + " min(s)");
}
if (seconds > 0) {
    System.out.println(seconds + " second(s)");
}
```

Note, I’m lazy and when it comes to date/time manipulation so I’ve used the available libraries

Answer (score 0):

You may check this code, but I did not include seconds. I started in `minutes`.

For seconds, you may use the `timeInterval` to get the `%` of seconds.

```
public static final String INVALID_MESSAGE = "Invalid Value";
 
public static void printYearsAndDays(long minutes) {
    if (minutes < 0) {
        System.out.println(INVALID_MESSAGE);
    } else {
 
        int timeInterval = 60;
        int dayInterval = 24;
        int yearInterval = 365;
        long remainingMinutes = minutes % timeInterval;
        long remainingHours = (minutes / timeInterval) % dayInterval;
        long remainingDays = ((minutes / timeInterval) / dayInterval) % yearInterval;
        long remainingYears = ((minutes / timeInterval) / dayInterval) / yearInterval;
 
        String minutesDisplay = remainingMinutes + "min ";
        String hoursDisplay = remainingHours + "h ";
        String daysDisplay = remainingDays + " d";
        String yearsDisplay = remainingYears + " y";
 
 
        System.out.println(minutes+ " min = "+ yearsDisplay + " and " + daysDisplay);
    }
}
```